# F# : not sure how to start

Tags: f#

Need help with this,

1. Write a function, that takes 2 StraightLine and returns the intersecting point as a tuple `(x,y)`. If there is no solution, there shall be used an "Exception"
2. Change your solution in assignment "1", so instead of using an "Exception" you need to use the option "None" if there is no solution. If there is a solution, use the `Some(x,y)` expression.
3. Solve assignment "1" again, but define a record-type Line with brackets a and b til represent a line. `y=3x+4` is for example represented with the brackets `{a=3.0; b=4.0}`.

Comment: This is not a coding service. We are not here to do your homework for you. Try to solve it yourself, google if you get stuck and if you still can't solve it, come back and ask a *specific* question about a *specific* problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.

```
type Line = {a:double; b:double}

let LinesIntersection x y = 
    if x.a <> y.a then 
        Some ((x.b - y.b)/(y.a - x.a), (y.a*x.b - x.a*y.b)/(y.a - x.a))
    else None

let l1 = {a = 2.0; b = -3.0}
let l2 = {a = -3.0; b = 2.0}
let l3 = {a = 2.0; b = 4.0}

LinesIntersection l1 l2 |> printfn "%A"
LinesIntersection l1 l3 |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
Some (1.0, -1.0)
<null>
```

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uNcTEL

The rest do yourself. Does not work - show an attempt solutions

Comment: @Fsharper91 - before you ask another homework question please read this:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions