# line line intersection fsharp

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I'm having problems with writing a line-line intersection function. This is what I have so far:

```
type Line = float*float

let LinesIntersection x y = 
    if x.a <> y.a then 
        Some ((x.b - y.b)/(y.a - x.a), (y.a*x.b - x.a*y.b)/(y.a - x.a))
    else None

let l1 = (2.0,-3.0)
let l2 = (-3.0, 2.0)
let l3 = (2.0, 4.0)

LinesIntersection l1 l2 |> printfn "%A"
LinesIntersection l1 l3 |> printfn "%A"
```

Output:

```
stdin(73,19): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
Line    
but here has type
    float * float
```

Any help?

Comment: What are you expecting e.g. `x.a` to do? Tuples do not have an `a` member...

Comment: They may want to change the `Line` declaration to `type Line = { a: float; b: float}` and set l1 to l3 accordingly: `let l1 = { a=2.0; b= -3.0 }`

Comment: I'm trying to get values returned as tuples

Comment: Downvote. Sorry, but you take the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683811/f-assignment-not-sure-how-to-start/32689058#32689058 and change the line Type = {a:double; b:double} type line = float*float. You're not even trying to do something themselves. What exactly is the problem? you already almost have everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
type Line = {a:float; b:float}

let LinesIntersection x y = 
    if x.a <> y.a then 
        Some ((x.b - y.b)/(y.a - x.a), (y.a*x.b - x.a*y.b)/(y.a - x.a))
    else None

let l1 = {a=2.0; b=3.0}
let l2 = {a= -3.0; b=2.0}
let l3 = {a=2.0; b=4.0}

LinesIntersection l1 l2 |> printfn "%A"
LinesIntersection l1 l3 |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: I don't think this will work without type annotations on `LinesIntersection` or pattern matching on `x` and `y`.

Comment: Run it and you'll see it gives `Some (-0.2, 2.6)   <null>`.